# How to Sync Multiple ListViews Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I am displaying data: 3 fields for each record, 3 ListViews are currently displaying the corresponding data.

I did this so that I could have columns for the data.

The problem is: When you have enough data that scrolling is neccassary, I need to sync the ListViews.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Or is there a better solution for displaying this data in column format?

Thanks

Comment: A better solution is just to have a single listview which draws a custom view (seen as columns) as each row...

Comment: As Ken mentioned, using multiple Listviews to solve this problem is not the right solution, you'd create a column like layout for a row and use it across all the rows to get that columnar effect. On the other hand, you could use AbsListView.OnScrollListener to observe scroll in one list and use ListView.smoothScrollToPosition() to scroll other lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try registering a scroll listener on each of the lists (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html)

Then update the position of the other 2 lists whenever that gets called back (either http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo(int, int) or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int))

I wouldn't recommend this though as it will not scroll smoothly or at the same time!

As Ken mentioned in a comment a single list with a custom view would work much better - consider a LinearLayout with a weightSum of 3 and your 3 views (or sub-layouts) all having a weight of 1, to get 3 equally spaced columns.

Comment: np, glad to be able to help. Just for any others who may have the same problem - did you go with the sync solution or the single list with new layout?